# How can i fix the error tensorflow has not attribute 'ConfigProto' witthout deprecating?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, retinanet

i'm trying to train a Retinanet on my Dataset with this command line :

```
  retinanet-train --batch-size 4 --steps 349 --epochs 50 --weights logos/resnet50_coco_best_v2.1.0.h5 --snapshot-path logos/snapshots csv logos/retinanet_train.csv logos/retinanet_classes.csv
```

And I get this Error :

```
    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'ConfigProto'
```

I know that , this is related to the version of ***Tensorlow*** , in the new version ConfigProto disappeared , but i want to fix it without 're-installing' the old version the ***1.14***, cause otherwise it will be a mess.

Any suggestion would be super appreciated , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since `tf.ConfigProto` is deprecated in TF 2.0, use `tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()` instead by replacing the occurences of `tf.ConfigProto()` in the `retinanet-train` code (assuming that's where `tf.ConfigProto()` is being called). Link to [tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/ConfigProto) here.

Comment: this is what i want to do , the problem is , i don't know how to locate the Retinanet-Train Code , any suggestion on how to do it ? , thank you

Comment: Here's a workaround for the same issue some have used (for retinanet): https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/issues/1171#issuecomment-550973614 . You need to use a specific fork to be able to run the retinanet code with TF2.0. Hope this solves the issue.